# Why can't I transpose a raster across the pole with rasterio or gdal, and how could it be done?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, rasterio, affine-transformation

I have a raster in e.g epsg:4326, it covers all world, from 180E to 180W, from 90S to 90N. I want to re-project a part of it to [epsg:3031](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-antarctic-polar-stereographic/) and also change the grid size and resolution.

Here is a minimal, and working example:

```
from rasterio.transform import from_bounds, from_origin
from rasterio.warp import reproject, Resampling
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

km = 1000

my_raster = rasterio.open("my_raster.tif") #Global raster
west, south, east, north = -180, -90, 180, 90 
src_crs = my_raster.crs
src_shape = src_height, src_width = my_raster.shape
src_transform = from_bounds(west, south, east, north, src_width, src_height)
source = my_raster.read(1)

dst_crs = {'init': 'EPSG:3031'} # WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic
print(src_crs['init'])

dst_transform = from_origin(0*km, 3000*km, 50*km, 50*km)
print(dst_transform)

my_array = np.zeros((120, 120))
my_array[:] = np.nan

reproject(source,
          my_array,
          src_transform=src_transform,
          src_crs=src_crs,
          dst_transform=dst_transform,
          dst_crs=dst_crs,
          resampling=Resampling.bilinear)

plt.imshow(my_array)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output from code above]

This raster only contains the eastern hemisphere, but I want to include all Antarctica.

When I change the transform, to e.g. `dst_transform = from_origin(-1000*km, 3000*km, 50*km, 50*km)` the code freezes. I've tried a number of other transformations, this is the only case that doesn't work, but I need to have my raster in Antarctic stereographic.

How can I redefine my transformation matrix so that my reprojected raster contains also Western Antarctica?

I prefer to use rasterio, as it works good for the rest of my project, but any suggestion is welcome.

UPDATE: 
I tried gdal warp with Python wrapper, but also no success. Now, I can define the right bounds, but I got a hole around the South Pole instead.

A minimal (not) working example:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

km = 1000

my_array = gdal.Warp('', 'my_raster.tif', 
            format = 'MEM', 
            width = 120, height = 120, 
            dstSRS='EPSG:3031', 
            outputBounds= (-2000*km, -2000*km, 2000*km, 2000*km),
            resampleAlg = gdal.GRIORA_NearestNeighbour).ReadAsArray()

ds = None

plt.imshow(my_array[1,:,:])
plt.show()
```

[image]